# llvm clang 2.6: "not using the clang compiler for C++ inputs "

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

LLVM 2.6 + clang.

Trying to compile C++ file and got:

```
clang: warning: not using the clang compiler for C++ inputs
```

How can I start clang in C++ mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would get the trunk code. C++ support has been much improved since 2.6.

The clang driver Makefile in tools/clang/tools/driver uses the CLANG_IS_PRODUCTION define to control whether C++ is on or off. CLANG_IS_PRODUCTION means C++ off. The default for a trunk build is no CLANG_IS_PRODUCTION (i.e. a development build).

Answer (score 1):

I know that the trunk code has c++ enabled. Perhaps you could use that instead?

Comment: this message means, that c++ support was disabled at build? How can I enable it?